# What is the identity section of a vector bundle?

Tags: terminology, vector-bundles

In this lectures notes [Geometric wave equation](https://www.math.uni-potsdam.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Prof-Geometrie/Dokumente/Lehre/Lehrmaterialien/Waves.pdf) by Christian Bär at page 122 he has

> Definition 3.4.1. Let $M$ be a timeoriented connected Lorentzian manifold. Let $P$ be a normally hyperbolic operator acting on sections in a vector bundle $E$ over $M$. A linear map $G_{+}$: $\mathcal{D}(M, E) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M, E)$ satisfying
> (i) $P \circ G_{+}=\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}$,  ....

Here $C^{\infty}(M, E)$  is the space of infinty differentiable section  and $\mathcal{D}(M, E)$ is the space of compact supported section for the vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$

What is the section $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer was wrong, I was misled by the words in your final question, referring to $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}$ as a *section*.

Each individual element of $\mathcal{D}(M,E)$ is section of the bundle $E \mapsto M$, and $\mathcal{D}(M,E)$ is the space of all sections.

And as you noticed in the comments, $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}$ is a certain operator on $\mathcal{D}(M,E)$, i.e. it inputs a section and outputs a section.

Namely, $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}$ is the identity operator, whose output equals its input:
$$\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}(\varphi)=\varphi \quad\text{for all $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(M,N)$}
$$

So what that equation $P \circ G_{+}=\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}$ says is that $G_+$ is a right inverse for the operator $P$ with respect to operator composition: When $P$ is composed in advance by $G_+$, the result is the identity operator.

Comment: by Identity you mean $0$?

Comment: Yes, the additive identity element of a vector space is traditionally denoted $0$. Keep in mind, however: each fiber of $E$ has its own identity element. For this reason, many writers will use some special notation to refer to the identity element of the fiber over each $x \in M$. Example notations might include $0_x$ or $\text{Id}_x$ or something like that.

Comment: So, for example, if one uses $0_x$ to denote the identity element of the fiber of $E$ over $x \in M$ then one has the formula $$\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}(x) = 0_x$$

Comment: I think $\mathcal{D}(M, E)$ is an operator since $P$  and $G$ are operators

Comment: Ah yes, that's right, and your words in the post calling $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}(M, E)}$ a *section* are wrong. I'll change my answer.